# How to launch an executable by inheriting parent environment?

Tags: powershell

```
$start =([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($PathForExe)
```

the above command launches only exe in PowerShell environment.
How to launch Executable from its parent environment in PowerShell script.

Comment: What do you mean by "launch from its parent environment"? It's not clear to me what doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start()` and (I assume) `Start-Process` will  automatically launch a child process